# mysql rollback by error HANDLER not working

Tags: mysql

I just build a stored procedure to test transaction in mysql.

But somehow it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
USE `test`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `testTran`;
DELIMITER $$
USE `test`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testTran`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION rollback;
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO `test`.`books`(`name`,`number`) VALUES ('asd', 20);
    ALTER TABLE `test`.`books` ADD COLUMN `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL  AFTER `number` ;
    COMMIT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Inside transaction, the second command is create an exist column which will be fail. What I expect is the first insert will be rollback. But actually, it's not. The insert do work.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use transactions you need to convert the tables to a transaction table like InnoDB.

Optionally, you can rollback changes made by your stored procedure using SAVEPOINT.

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK TO identifier;

SAVEPOINT identifier;

START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO `test`.`books`(`name`,`number`) VALUES ('asd', 20);
ALTER TABLE `test`.`books` ADD COLUMN `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL  AFTER `number` ;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks for help. The table is using InnoDB. And I try your solution. But I got this error "Error Code: 1305. SAVEPOINT identifier does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

The ALTER TABLE statement causes an [implicit COMMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html) before it is executed.